# Disponibilizando aquivos scss e ttf em library angular

Tags: angular, library

Estou criando uma biblioteca Angular com NPM e gostaria de ter uma pasta de css e fontes personalizadas disponibilizadas no build final, sendo possível eu apenas importar os arquivos scss nas aplicações que irão instalar essa biblioteca direto nos arquivos scss deles.

Estrutura da lib:

```
src/
--lib/
----styles/
------variables.scss
------custom.scss
----components/
--public_api.ts
--test.ts
package.json
```

O import seria algo tipo?

```
@import '~@minhalib/styles/variables.scss'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Feito

Não sei se é a melhor maneira, mas tai

Coloque esse código em scripts no arquivo package.json, então use npm run build-mylib que ele irá buildar e jogar em um tgz

```
    "build-mylib": "ng build mylib && npm run cp-styles && npm run cp-assets && cd dist/mylib/ && npm pack",
    "cp-styles": "cpx \"./projects/mylib/src/lib/styles/**/*\" \"./dist/mylib/styles\"",
    "cp-assets": "cpx \"./projects/mylib/src/lib/assets/**/*\" \"./dist/mylib/assets\""
```